# Swift Switch case "not"

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I've got two enums:

```
public enum ServerState {
  case Connecting
  case Open
  case LoggedIn
  case Closed
  case Error(NSError)
}

enum TransportLayerState {
  case Disconnected(NSError?)
  case Connecting
  case Connected
}
```

I need to switch between them if and return 'false' if the ServerState is set to a state not possible by the underlying TL State.  For instance, it would return false if `serverState == .Open && tlState == .Disconnected`.  I'm attempting to do this using a switch statement, but I'm finding that what I really want is to match a case where one of the state is *not* a specific state.  For instance:

```
switch (serverState, tlState) {
case (.Connecting, !.Connecting): return false
case (.Closed, !.Disconnected(.None)): return false
case (.Error(_), !.Disconnected(.Some(_)): return false
case (.Open, !.Connected), (.LoggedIn, !.Connected): return false
default: return true
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work because you cannot place `!` before a case statement.  My only other option is to specify all the *allowable* cases, which are far more numerous. It makes more sense to specify the restrictions and allow all other state combinations, but I'm not sure how to do this.  Any ideas?  I'm also trying to avoid nested switch statements.

Note: I'm aware that I could do this using Swift 2's `if case`, but I can't use Swift 2 right now as this is production code.  So please respond with solutions in Swift 1.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since all patterns are checked sequentially (and the first match "wins"),
you could do the following:

```
switch (serverState, tlState) {

case (.Connecting, .Connecting): return true // Both connecting 
case (.Connecting, _): return false  // First connecting, second something else

case (.Closed, .Disconnected(.None)): return true
case (.Closed, _): return false

// and so on ...
```

So generally, matching a case where one of the state is *not* a specific state can be done with two patterns: The first *matches* the state,
and the second is the wildcard pattern (`_`) which then matches all other
cases.

Comment: Hmmm.... ok.  That works, although it essentially doubles my case statements.  In this "case" (pun intended) I actually end up with more statements than if simply specify the allowable transitions.  But it does work.  So I'll wait a little while and if I can't find a better solution I'll accept yours.

Comment: @AaronHayman: Sure, no hurry. Actually I did not count how many allowed combinations remain.

Comment: In this case it's not too many more than the disallowed ones.  So really, doing it either way is not that big of a deal here.  But I could definitely see situations where the allowable combinations far outweigh the disallowed, so I think the question is pertinent.  My example was simply the closest one at hand.

Answer (score 2):

One possible answer I found was to make `TransportLayerState` equatable.  In that case I could do this:

```
switch serverState {
case .Connecting where tlState != .Connecting: return false
case .Closed where tlState != .Disconnected(nil): return false
case let .Error(err) where tlState != .Diconnected(err): return false
...
default: return true
}
```

I do end up having to write a bit of code in `TransportLayerState` enum to make it equatable, so not sure if it's worth the effort, but it does work.